# Relative Layout: difference between layout_alignBottom and layout_above

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have read document about those two attributes of relative layout, and try some examples, but still not recognize what difference between them. I have tried some test, but often i have same result, and sometimes, different, but i cannot explain.

Here is description on Android Document :

```
android:layout_above
Positions the bottom edge of this view above the given anchor view ID. Accommodates bottom margin of this view and top margin of anchor view.

android:layout_alignBottom
Makes the bottom edge of this view match the bottom edge of the given anchor view ID. Accommodates bottom margin.
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This image explains everything :)

[image]

above: the bottom edge of view is placed on top edge of view A

alignBottom: the bottom edge of a view is on the same line View B is.

Comment: Image is more than 1000 words.

Comment: fgeorgiew, tried `alignBottom` with two `TextView`s and `A` seems to overlap with `B`. Try it out...

Answer (score 2):

```
android:layout_above
```

this `View`'s bottom edge is where referenced `View`'s **top** edge is.

```
android:layout_alignBottom
```

this `View`'s bottom edge is where referenced `View`s **bottom** edge is.

If you want to see it in action, I suggest adding `gravity="center"` (not `layout_gravity` - there is a difference) to `RelativeLayout`, so the first `View` is centered and the second is layed out above or at the same place as first. Use `android:layout_toRightOf` to make them not overlap.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:layout_above :
```

In simple login page . User id edit text is `layout_above` to Password edittext.

```
android:layout_alignBottom
```

The label User id and user id edit text is using `android:layout_alignBottom`